# I can't install Windows XP on my Dell laptop

Tags: windows-xp, laptop

I can't find windows xp achi drivers for Dell Inspiron 11 3180. I have tried searching for the drivers but I can't find it.

Comment: Why would anyone make drivers for an OS that was long-dead before the laptop was first released? Or the other way round, how could anyone have made XP drivers at the time for equipment that wasn't yet invented?

Comment: Windows XP is incompatible with any device where it does not support CSM.  Dell does not support Windows XP on your machine.  If I were to guess, you wouldn't even be able to install Windows XP successfully on your device, given the major limitation with CSM>

Answer (score 4):

The Dell Inspiron 11 3180 is a modern laptop that was released *this* year.  Windows XP came out in 2001 and support was [ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-xp-support) in 2014.  No computer manufacturer or OEM parts provider is going to write, release, or support new drivers for an old operating system that had reached its [End of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_product).

Answer (score 1):

Your Dell Inspiron came with a modern operating system that works - Windows 10.

If you prefer using Windows XP, you may use Hyper-V to create a
Generation 1 virtual machine and install XP on it.

The XP virtual machine will work correctly on your hardware, since its
hardware is supported by Hyper-V virtual devices.

But I would really recommend using Windows 10, rather than an old and
insecure operating system.

Answer (score 1):

As noted you cannot install XP natively on any modern hardware. Accordingly, you must install Windows XP in a virtual machine. I use VMware Workstation and have an XP machine here. It works just fine on a Windows 10 Host machine. There are other virtual machine apps, but VMware works best for me.

You need an XP Disk plus all 3 service packs. Look in the Microsoft Download Center and you will find the downloads.

You may have to search for any other system files you need as an XP machine no longer updates.

For SP2:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=18242

SP2 should cover SP1 so the one download is fine.

For SP3:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=55460

This should accomplish what you need, but remember, XP (even as a Virtual Machine) is hopelessly insecure so do not use it for much.